# AFNetworking 2.0 track file upload progress

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am relatively new to AFNetworking 2.0.  Using the code snippet below, I've been able to successfully upload a photo to my url. I would like to track the incremental upload progress, but I cannot find an example of doing this with version 2.0.  My application is iOS 7, so I've opted for AFHTTPSessionManager.

Can anyone offer an example of how to modify this snippet to track upload progress?

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"], 1.0);

[manager POST:@"http://myurl.com" parameters:dataToPost constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"attachment" fileName:@"myimage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, [task.response description]);
}];
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The interface of `AFHTTPSession` doesn't provide a method to set a progress block. Instead, you'll have to do the following:

```
// 1. Create `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` which will create your request.
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

// 2. Create an `NSMutableURLRequest`.
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://www.myurl.com"
                                    parameters:dataToPost
                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                       [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                                   name:@"attachment"
                                               fileName:@"myimage.jpg"
                                               mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                     }];

// 3. Create and use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to create an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from the `NSMutableURLRequest` that we just created.
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                       NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                     }];

// 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                    long long totalBytesWritten,
                                    long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
  NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

// 5. Begin!
[operation start];
```

In addition, you don't have to read the image via `UIImage` and then compress it again using JPEG to get an `NSData`. Just use `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]` to read the file directly from your bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. However, the block setUploadProgressBlock not called. It is just called only once after uploading finishes. Can you help me explain and fix it?

Comment: Please note that `-multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:` is now deprecated, you can use `-multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:error` instead (there is an additional error parameter)!

Answer (score 14):

It's true the interface of `AFHTTPSessionManager` doesn't provide a method to track the upload progress. **But** the `AFURLSessionManager` does.

As a inherited class of `AFURLSessionManager` `AFHTTPSessionManager` can track upload progress like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]  multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:kUploadImageURL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) name:@"uploadFile" fileName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} error:nil];

NSProgress *progress;
NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [[AFHTTPSessionManager sharedManager] uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //handle upload success
    } else {
        //handle upload failure
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
[progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

outside

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fractionCompleted"] && [object isKindOfClass:[NSProgress class]]) {
        NSProgress *progress = (NSProgress *)object;
        //progress.fractionCompleted tells you the percent in CGFloat
    }
}
```

#### Here is method 2(updated)

use `KVO` to track progress means `self` need to be alive during observation. The more elegant way is `AFURLSessionManager`'s method `setTaskDidSendBodyDataBlock`, like this:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setTaskDidSendBodyDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionTask *task, int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend) {
    //during the progress
}];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]  multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:kUploadImageURL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) name:@"uploadFile" fileName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} error:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //handle upload success
    } else {
        //handle upload failure
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: setTaskDidSendBodyDataBlock is called when all the data has been sent. It is not much of a gradual progress. how to get step by step percentage of progress? I am using dataTaskWithRequest:uploadProgress:downloadProgress:completionHandler:

Comment: The strange thing is that when it has finished uploading it is called multiple times. It might be some threading related problem

Comment: I missed NSURLSessionConfiguration with AFHTTPSessionManager. It got called gradually. Althought in dataTaskWithRequest:uploadProgress:downloadProgress:completi‌​onHandler:    uploadProgress is still being called after it is finished.

Comment: It seems it is also working right. I had my code in  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}); block, it is called at the end.