# AFNetworking download with progressive UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking, uialertview

I want to implement a `UIAlertView` which will show when `[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:]` will start doing its job and will disappear automatically when the job is done. One cool extra feature would be if I could display `UIProgressView` with progress of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

For now I'm checking if a have anything in Core Data and based on that I initialize `UIAlertView`:

```
if (![self coreDataHasEntriesForEntityName:@"Group"]) {
        downloadingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pobieranie" message:@"Trwa pobieranie grup" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Anuluj" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [self collectData];
    } else {
        NSError *error;
        [[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error];
    }
```

So to prevent from showing this alert when `UITableView` is already filled with data.
As you can see I'm calling this `[self collectData]` method which looks like:

```
-(void)collectData
{
    [downloadingAlert show];

    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:ALL_GROUPS parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        tempContext.parentContext = self.moc;

        [tempContext performBlock:^{

            // Doing something with responseObject

            if (![tempContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            [self.moc performBlock:^{
                NSError *error;
                if (![self.moc save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }

                [downloadingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

                [self.writer performBlockAndWait:^{
                    NSError *error;
                    if (![self.writer save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                }];

            }];
        }];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Show alert with info about failure
    }];
}
```

As you can see I'm programatically showing this `UIAlertView` and dismissing it when downloading is completed and `UITableView` is reloaded. But I have no clue how to add `UIProgressView` or how to dismiss this `UIAlertView` without using `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AFNetworking 2.0 HTTP POST Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951700/afnetworking-2-0-http-post-progress/21951824#21951824)

You can receive progress information if you will use the following method

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                         fromData:(NSData *)bodyData
                                         progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress
                                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

of AFHTTPSessionManager class

Comment: For my purpose this method would be better choice: `downloadTaskWithRequest:fromData:progress:completionHandler:` :)