# Upload file of huge size to server and track progress of uploading in iOS

Tags: ios, file-upload, nsurlconnection, httpclient, afnetworking

I have a requirement in my application, to upload a file (pdf,audio,video, etc) to server with huge sizes. I need to upload the file in background and also indicate the user with a progress bar.

I tried to Google and found few stack overflow pointers to use NSUrlconnection and implement delegate methods.some pointed to ASHTTPClient. I am looking for best solution or readymade solution, if it is available. I am posting here, hoping someone might have come across a similar requirement and whose pointers would help me a lot.

Any pointers and if possible with code snippets is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFNetworking 2.0 is a very powerful and well put together library for dealing with all kinds of HTTP requests. Once you use it the first time, you'll use it in all your projects for handling HTTP processes - http://afnetworking.com/

Comment: @Adam thanks for the quick reply. One more question about the progress indicator.Does the API take care of Breaking down the file into different chunks and upload sequentially and thus respond the progress. Plz correct if I am wrong.

Comment: This thread looks good for you  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533890/afnetworking-2-0-track-file-upload-progress