# Upload image from iOS to PHP

Tags: php, ios, nsurlconnection, image-uploading, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm trying to upload an image from my iOS App to my web server via PHP. Here is the following code:

```
-(void)uploadImage {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);   

    //1
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    //2
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


    NSString *urlString = @"http://mywebserver.com/script.php";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
    ;
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"iosfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //3
    self.uploadTask = [defaultSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imageData];

    //4
    self.progressBarView.hidden = NO;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    //5
    [uploadTask resume];
}

// update the progressbar
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.progressBarView setProgress:(double)totalBytesSent / (double)totalBytesExpectedToSend animated:YES];
    });
}

// when finished upload
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
        self.progressBarView.hidden = YES;
        [self.progressBarView setProgress:0.0];
    });

    if (!error) {
        // no error
        NSLog(@"no error");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error");
        // error
    }

}
```

And the following working simple PHP code:

```
<?php
$msg = " ".var_dump($_FILES)." ";
$new_image_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/pictures/" . $new_image_name);
?>
```

The application on iOS seems to upload the photo and the progressbar is working but I the file is not really uploaded when I check on the server files.

When I send the picture with the following code, it works perfectly (EDIT: but without the progressbar):

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

And idea where I am wrong ?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using the code that works?

Comment: @68cherries It is Synchronous, not a good idea. But `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is a good and easy substitution for the sync method.

Comment: @68cherries I'd like to display a progress bar and as I understand, the only way is to use the iOS7 `NSURLSessionUploadTask`

Comment: Or `connectionWithRequest:delegate:`.

Comment: If the progress bar is loading and you aren't getting any errors then I would guess something is wrong with the server-side code. Unfortunately I know nothing in php.

Comment: @68cherries That's why I'm stuck because I don't get why it works with the `NSURLConnection` way and not with the `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. If it works with the first one, it means that the PHP code is fine, isn't it ?

Comment: I think that my `NSMutableURLRequest *request` is not well constructed for the `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. If someone can help, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used the `AFNetworking` library to handle this. As I haven't found clear methods to do this on the web and on stackoverflow, here is my answer to easily post user's images from their iOS device to your server via PHP. Majority of the code comes from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533890/afnetworking-2-0-track-file-upload-progress).

```
-(void)uploadImage { 
    image = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(800, 800)];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);

    // 1. Create `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` which will create your request.
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"your_param": @"param_value"};

    NSError *__autoreleasing* error;
    // 2. Create an `NSMutableURLRequest`.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://www.yoururl.com/script.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                    name:@"userfile"
                                fileName:@"image.jpg"
                                mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    } error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error];
    // 3. Create and use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to create an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from the `NSMutableURLRequest` that we just created.
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                         NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                     }];

    // 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        //NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
        [self.progressBarView setProgress:(double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated:YES];
    }];

    // 5. Begin!
    operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];


    self.progressView.hidden = NO;
    [operation start];
}
```

I think it will help new xcoders.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do it with NSURLSession?  Im working on it right now but am having trouble.

Comment: Here is my post, although some SO'ers were too quick to mark it as a duplicate!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098056/why-do-i-get-undefined-index-uploading-image-to-php-from-ios-but-not-from-html

Comment: @marciokoko Couldn't figure it out how to do it with `NSURLSession`, but works fine with `AFNetworking`. If you do it this way, you'll get a cleaner code and you'll be able to handle the network errors more easily.