# PHP picture upload works on localhost but not on GoDaddy server

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, file-upload

We have been developing an application for both iOS and Android. One of our views uploads a picture to the server using POST. The android version works both in our local server and in the website. However, the iOS version is only working on our local server at the moment. Here is the code used to write the POST request:

NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

```
    // Create the request.
    NSString* afterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload.php?username=%@",username];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url,afterURL]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //------------------------------------------------------
    // used code from this tutorial: http://www.iriphon.com/2011/11/09/ios-uploading-an-image-from-your-iphone-to-a-server/
    NSString *boundary = @"-----InstantLabor";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // Now we need to append the different data 'segments'. We first start by adding the boundary.
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // This line of code came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728317/upload-image-to-the-php-server-from-ios
    //   By creating the string this way instead of the other way, we were able to successfully upload the picture!
    /*
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:
                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", @"dl"]]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     */

     [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[userfile]\";filename=\"dl.jpg\"\r\n"
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // We now need to tell the receiver what content type we have
    // In my case it's a png image. If you have a jpg, set it to 'image/jpg'
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Now we append the actual image data
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    // and again the delimiting boundary
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // adding the body we've created to the request
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    // Create url connection and fire request
    _parsedData = nil;
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When we were trying to get it to work in the local server, the above code didn't work until we switched

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[userfile]\";filename=\"dl.jpg\"\r\n"
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

with

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:
                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", @"dl"]]
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Even though it is creating the same string, one works and other one doesn't; but neither of them work when connecting to the website. Everything we've tried ends up spitting out

```
Undefined index: userfile
```

back at the application. Since one of them works, we know it's not a memory issue or a privileges issue. We have no idea what else could be causing the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Here is the deal, if you are having network issues run a network analyzer and find out what is happening, Charles Proxy is the OSX go-to analyzer, free 30 day trial. Run Charles Proxy on both and find the difference. The bad news is you really should learn something about http requests—"It will do you no harm": Ritchie Havens

Comment: Did you check the php.ini settings? Since the notice is userfile i assume this is your fileupload field?, it could be the post_max_size (or upload_max_filesize) is too small to deal with images.

Comment: Yes @David, the current post_max_size is set to 1Gb to make sure it's big enough. The problem seems to be that the picture is not being sent correctly, even though it works on our local server. Thank you.

Comment: ask the hosting site to debug, sometimes they have settings that override your php.ini. Once you're sure userfile is properly being submitted from your browser, and this is the case as localhost can handle it...

Comment: did you able to find the answer of this ?

Answer (score 0):

After two days of tweaking, testing. etc we had no luck solving the issue. Instead we decided to incorporate AFNetworking and follow this [Upload image from iOS to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667226/upload-image-from-ios-to-php) to get our picture upload to work.