# Xcode upload Imagines

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i will create a new project that it save an image to a server 
i don't know whats i do 
i search in this site but i don't find a solutions
My apps now take a photo from the camera or from the iPhone albums but i won't to upload this photo to my server

this is my ViewController.m :

'

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Non è presente una Camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }

}

- (void)useCamera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = YES;
    }
}
- (void)useCameraRoll:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)useUpload:(UIButton *)sender {


}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
    }
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

Comment: i cant find code to upload yorr image to server

Comment: is it mysql php server?

Comment: then you need to call it form ios. so that the file gets uploaded on server from your device

Comment: You are not posted the code for image upload

Comment: Check this link for image upload code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667226/upload-image-from-ios-to-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code from my app to post an image to our web server:

```
// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];                                    
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];
```

[Copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567771/1066828)

This was first answer in [Mr. Google reply](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW556KW556&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=upload%20photo%20ios)